# Stopping slides scrolling in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have some back-up slides at the end of my presentation, which are accessed by means of hyperlinks. For this reason, I would like to "stop" the scrolling of the slides (done by clicking PageUp / Page Down or rotating the mouse wheel ) at my last "actual" slide, preventig me to show the accessory slides by mistake  during the presentation.
Is this possible somehow ?
I am not sure whether I made myself clear or not ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=mainBody]
txt 1

\hyperlink{accessorySlide}{\beamerbutton{jump to accessory slide}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
txt 2

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Thank you
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=accessorySlide]
accessory information 
\hyperlink{mainBody}{\beamerbutton{jump back to main body}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I'd like, when in presentation mode, not to be possible to scroll beyond the "thank you" slide

Comment: A suggestion: a couple of copies of the thank you slide to absorb a misclick or two

Comment: Thought that ... yet if a "clean" solution is available it would be preferable

Comment: Section 5.1.4 of the beamer manual implies a clean solution.  Note that `\againframe` gives a way to repeat a frame without copy-pasting

Comment: yep, you can define an \appendix,  which can be managed differently respect to the main body, but could not find a way to stop the scrolling at the end of the main body

Comment: Same here -- my reading of the manual suggested that you should be able to stop scrolling but no.

Comment: and `\againframe` inserts another page into the pdf rather than looping using a hyperlink

Comment: It turns out that this has already been asked -- I only found the original when I tried to follow the same approach myself

Comment: Having voted to close, the modifications required to make the duplicate work here were a little more than I thought.  But I have a working answer (@samcarter)

Comment: I vote for reopening the question. The linked duplicate is more about automated looping for animation purposes. Here it was asked just to prevent the viewer from going past the final official slide. I have a neat solution too I would like to post here.

Comment: I honestly don't see how the question can be considered answered. I've tried the solutions proposed in the other question and they don't work ...

Comment: Wait for the question to be reopened. Hope this happens soon.

Comment: @samcarter : Would you please reopen this question?

Comment: @AlexG done   ....

Comment: @ChrisH the question is open again

Comment: @samcarter thanks. My answer is on my Dropbox so I'll see if I can paste it. It's very heavily based on the near duplicate but with subtleties I couldn't explain in a comment (@ dario)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the sub-page navigation feature of the PDF specification. It works in **Acrobat Reader DC** and requires the **Full Screen** (Ctrl-L) mode.

Note that the backlinks (`GoBack` action) from the auxiliary slides are not functional in A-Readers X and XI. `GoBack` worked in AR-9 and is back in AR-DC, fortunately.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Intro}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
  Read more \hyperlink{aux1}{here}.

  Read even more \hyperlink{aux2}{here}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}
  Read more \hyperlink{aux2}{here}.

  Read even more \hyperlink{aux2}{here}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% In FULL SCREEN mode of Acrobat Reader this code
% doesn't allow the viewer to go past the "Summary" page.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\edef\pdfpageattrSaved{{\the\pdfpageattr}}
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{%
    \the\pdfpageattr
    /PresSteps <<
      /NA<</S/Named/N/NOP>> %no-op on page open
      /Next<<
        /NA<</S/GoTo/D (slideSummary)>>
      >>
    >>
  }%
}%
\x
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}{Summary}\hypertarget{slideSummary}{}
  Thank you for your attention!
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% reset no normal behaviour
\expandafter\pdfpageattr\pdfpageattrSaved
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}{Aux slide 1}\hypertarget{aux1}{}
  Go \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{back}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Aux slide 2}\hypertarget{aux2}{}
  Go \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{back}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work to me ... the presentation scroll from "slideSummary" to "Aux slide 1" and "Aux slide 2" ...

Comment: @dario What pdf viewer are you using? I tested it with adobe and I don't scroll to the backup slide.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Reader XI

Comment: @dario I have also AR XI.

Comment: Guys, don't know what to tell you ... I just copy the code, compile it, open the PDF and it scrolls through ALL the  slides

Comment: Full screen (Ctrl-L)?

Comment: yes :-( , presentation mode

Comment: I have just upgraded to AR-DC for Windows. It perfectly works here (even the backlinks).

Comment: @dario What if you use the mouse buttons for navigating (left is forwards, right is backwards). I can use all arrow keys and PgUp/PgDn.

Comment: I cleaned up the code somewhat.

Comment: It scrolls through all the slides using mouse buttons as well ...

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the answer to the previous question about looping a final slide or two. Instead it flips back to the final slide when a copy of that slide is advanced to. I've only tested it in Adobe reader X for Windows so far (in presentation mode).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Title
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Content
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=TheEnd]
    Thank you
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr /Dur 0.2
    /AA <<
      /O <<
        /S/JavaScript /JS(
          var retVal=app.setTimeOut( "this.pageNum--;", 10);
        )
      >>
    >>
  }%
}%
\x
\againframe{TheEnd} %auto-advancing frames


\begin{frame}
    Backup
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Formatting is stuffed up by the double-right-pointy-bracket. It's not really fixable from my phone but I'll edit when I'm on a computer.

Comment: I just tried to fix the formatting. Can you please check if everything is ok?

Comment: This does not work to me: scrolling twice when in "TheEnd"  frame it moves to the backup slide

Comment: @dario what are you using to view it, and is javascript enabled?  I'm now on a machine that doesn't have adobe reader (evince instead) and the javascript is  ignored.  If I had adobe reader I'd test reducing the "10" in the line with `setTimeOut`, I'd also test reducing `/Dur 0.2`.  It might be possible to find a sweet spot where a double-tap gets you into the backup slides easily but you don't accidentally press twice too easily.

Comment: using Adobe Reader XI ... JS seems to be activated

Comment: I wonder if they've done something to presentation mode between X and XI then.  I've got a feeling about a presentation mode and a separate fullscreen mode.  How do you launch it? I use ctrl+L.

Comment: presentation mode (ctrl+L)

Comment: @ChrisH Works for me also with XI

Comment: @ChrisH But it seems one can not follow any links to the backup slides. (tried with the `\hyperlink/\hypertarget` syntax from the other answer.)

Comment: @samcarter The GoBack action is bugged in Readers X and XI. If you upgrade to AR DC or old AR-9 the backlinks work.

Comment: Guys, don't know what to tell you ... I just copy the code, compile it, open the PDF and it scrolls through ALL the  slides

Comment: It's sounds like the repeat code might be too early but I don't have access to a Windows machine over the weekend.